# How can I fix a leaky tap (exterior of the house) that I can't turn off the water source?

Tags: water, leak, faucet, valve, taps

I have a leaky tap that's dripping water. I saw many videos teaching people how to fix it. However, the first step always involves turning off the water source from the inside.

I have two water valves on the opposite side from the exterior leaky tap. I turned them all the way to the end clock-wise, but the water from the leaky tap still goes strong.

Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your house main, while fixing this.  It would behoove you to plan this when no other household members need water. And prepare to do it quickly.

I recently had a similar problem, but my house shutoffs didn't work either.
I had to call a plumber, who called the town, and shut off the water to my house at the street, while the plumber replaced both main shutoffs (either side of the meter) and replaced the leaky exterior faucet shutoff as well.  Best practices these days for shutoff valves are "ball valves" as they are less likely to fail than the traditional rubber washers on seats.

Comment: Where will I be able to find the house main water valve? In the basement or under the kitchen sink?

Comment: look for the water meter.  it should be immediately adjacent to it.  commonly it will have a large blue handle.

Comment: @personalprivacyadvocate Dunno where you live but I can guarantee that  it's rare in the USA to see a blue handle.  More likely a yellow cutoff-valve handle, but in houses of greater age, is often a plain old round handle.

Comment: Right, I had red round handles on a gate and a traditional valve.  One on each side of the meter, in the basement.    But houses and water supplies are different.